# /sbin/shutdown -h now; not working in crontab

Tags: cron, shutdown

I've made a script to update and upgrade at 12.15 every Friday and after both of these jobs have been completed shut down.

The updates work fine, however it does not shut down afterwards. I've tried to look it up and used the suggestions that I could find so far, but it doesn't seem to do anything, this is my script:

```
#crontab
#minute(s) hour(s) day(s) month(s) weekday(s) command(s)

15 12 * * 5 (/usr/bin/apt-get -y update; /usr/bin/apt-get -y upgrade; /usr/bin/touch /home/pi/cron_output.log;) 2>&1 >> /home/pi/cron_output.log; /sbin/shutdown -h now;
```

The /sbin/shutdown -h now; part appears to not be working and I have no clue on how to fix it

I'm running this on a raspberry pi.

Comment: What is the location of this crontab entry? If in `/etc/crontab`, you would need to specify a user (e.g. `root`) before the command. If it is in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi` (the location if you edited it as the `pi` user via `crontab -e`), then the `pi` user might not have sufficient access to run `/sbin/shutdown`. On my Raspberry Pi, the pi user is prompted for credentials when running `/sbin/shutdown`.

Comment: The crontab is stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi` it might be the case that `pi` does not have sufficient privileges. So does that mean that I should create a new crontab with `sudo crontab -e -u root`?

Comment: I tried it an that seems to be the problem, thank you

Comment: Glad it worked! It might be easy to forget where the entry is if it's in root's crontab, although that certainly works. I would probably put it in the existing `/etc/crontab` or create a new file in `/etc/cron.d`. The only difference in format between those and a specific user's crontab is that the username needs to be specified, e.g. `15 12 * * 5 root command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER GIVEN BY [cherdt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86787/cherdt), I ONLY POST BECAUSE IT'S A COMMENT AND I WANT TO CLOSE THIS QUESTION

I messed up the privileges, it had to be run as root.
Either use `/usr/bin/sudo` before commands or create crontab as `root`